# How to restrict all the Contact Name fields using validation rule?

Tags: trigger, community, validation, validation-rule, contact

Tried creating a validation rule as below,but i still can edit the suffix, salutation on page layout.
how to restrict salutation,Suffix, do they have any api names for this or should i consider trigger for this?

AND(
    OR(
        ISCHANGED(FirstName), 
        ISCHANGED(LastName)
    ),
    $Profile.Name = 'User'
)

Comment: Do you just want to check salutation or first,lastname as well?

Comment: The [SOAP API reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) is a good place to find objects' field information.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'Salutation' picklist  like->

> AND( OR( ISCHANGED(FirstName), ISCHANGED(LastName),ISCHANGED(Salutation) ), $Profile.Name = 'User' )